# Change direction of menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I downloaded a nice menu that is called "jQuery mega menu", And original Demo is here "http://www.htmldrive.net/items/demo/872/Nice-Multiple-jQuery-Mega-Drop-Down-Menu"

I tried to change direction of it for RTL languages like hebrew , arabic , farsi. I almost succeeded. This is RTL Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/H5rq6/embedded/result/

I faced a little problem. When I hover mouse on single column menu like "about us" as you can see in my demo. Menu fix like LTR but I wanted to fix like rtl. I don't know what's my problem.

```
// Calc Required Left Margin incl additional required for right align
var marginLeft = (totalItemWidth - parentWidth + 35);
var subLeft = parentLeft - marginLeft;
if (subLeft < 0) {
$('.sub-container', this).css('left', '0');
}else {
$('.sub-container', this).css('left', parentLeft + 'px').css('margin-left', -marginLeft + 'px');;
}
```

this is what I changed.

Comment: you're talking about the position of the sub menu right?

Comment: Yes exactly. As you can see sub menu is fit from left not right.

Answer (score 1):

you need to substract the parentWidth from your offset:

```
$('.sub-container', this).css('left', parentLeft-parentWidth  + 'px').css('margin-left', -marginLeft + 'px');
```

Comment: I had tried this before but doesn't work. exactly same as before.

Comment: can you upload this so I can see?

Comment: It seems that your calculation of parentWidth is not correct.. I'm pretty sure you're evaluating the a tag of the menu.. try to do it like this: var parentWidth = $(this).outerWidth(true);

Comment: it's changed a little. but not the solution yet. you can edit it via jsfiddle there's an option to edit it. http://jsfiddle.net/xc2yq/1/light/